# Need to update a column in a table from referencing from other table without hardcoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am currently working on a query which needs to update the column posting_ID in transaction table based on the information from Contract table for each client.

For example, the transaction table have 3 rows of data with different Posting_IDs. But these IDs needs to be updated by referencing into Contract table which will have Contract_NM column. Below is the picture which describes which Contract_NMs should go into what Posting_ID.
I can easily do this by writing a case statement and hardcoding the values, but our requirement is not to hardcode it.

```
Create Table #Transaction 
(ID int, Posting_ID Varchar(10), Contract_NM varchar(25), Client_NM varchar(25))

Insert Into #Transaction
Values 
(1, '94260','LC01','ACA'),(2, '94260','LC02','ACA'),(3, '12458','LC03','ACA'),(4, 
'92250','LC04','ACA'),(5, '92252','LC05','ACA')

 Select * from #Transaction

 Create Table #Contract
 (Posting_ID Varchar(10), Contract_NM varchar(25), Client_NM varchar(25))

  Insert Into #Contract
  Values
  ('94265',N'LC01,LC02','ACA'),('12422',N'LC03','ACA'),('94260',N'LC04,LC05','ACA')

   Select * from #Contract
```

Now, based on the data provided, I need to update Posting_ID column in Transaction table by referencing the Contract_NM column from the Contract table.

Can someone help with the solution here?

Comment: The correct approach is to refactor the Contract table so that your not storing multiple values in one column (`'LC04,LC05'`); i.e. have a row for each posting_ID & Contract_NM so you can then update across a JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alex, is there any way we can write the query to get this into separate rows and put that result into a different temp table and use that for the join?

Comment: If you were using a supported verion of SQL Server then the easy solution is string_split(), probaby the answer to 50% of sql questions; on 2012 you'll need to Google for a string splitter function, of which there are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DATA**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transaction') is not null)
    DROP TABLE #Transaction;

Create Table #Transaction (ID int, Posting_ID Varchar(10), Contract_NM varchar(25), Client_NM varchar(25));

Insert Into #Transaction
Values 
    (1, '94260','LC01','ACA'),
    (2, '94260','LC02','ACA'),
    (3, '12458','LC03','ACA'),
    (4, '92250','LC04','ACA'),
    (5, '92252','LC05','ACA');

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Contract') is not null)
    DROP TABLE #Contract;

Create Table #Contract (Posting_ID Varchar(10), Contract_NM varchar(25), Client_NM varchar(25));

Insert Into #Contract
Values
    ('94265',N'LC01,LC02','ACA'),
    ('12422',N'LC03','ACA'),
    ('94260',N'LC04,LC05','ACA');
```

**Query**

```
WITH contract_split(Posting_ID, Contract_NM, Contract_NM_list) AS
(
    SELECT
        Posting_ID,
        CAST(LEFT(Contract_NM, CHARINDEX(',', Contract_NM + ',') - 1) as nvarchar),
        STUFF(Contract_NM, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Contract_NM + ','), '')
    FROM #Contract

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Posting_ID,
        CAST(LEFT(Contract_NM_list, CHARINDEX(',', Contract_NM_list + ',') - 1) as nvarchar),
        STUFF(Contract_NM_list, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Contract_NM_list + ','), '')
    FROM contract_split
    WHERE
        Contract_NM_list > ''
)
UPDATE t
    SET t.Posting_ID = cs.Posting_ID
FROM contract_split cs
JOIN #Transaction t ON t.Contract_NM = cs.Contract_NM
```

**Details** The CTE takes the Contract_NM and adds a comma and then selects everything to the first comma it finds. The stuff then replaces the first Contract_NM up to the comma with nothing and stores the rest for the next recursive call. **Note**: you can add trim if your data has whitespace. When the CTE is done, it will contain all the values in rows. Add OPTION (maxrecursion 0) if you are running this on many rows.

The update joins the CTE to the #Transaction table for updating. I just replaced the #Transaction Posting_ID with the one from the #Contract table. Not sure if that was your intent or not.

**Transaction Table Results**

| pre-update | Posting_ID (after update) | Contract_NM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 94260 | 94265 | LC01 |
| 94260 | 94265 | LC02 |
| 12458 | 12422 | LC03 |
| 92250 | 94260 | LC04 |
| 92252 | 94260 | LC05 |